# Enable diff-mode for files with diff-ish content

Tags: major-mode, diff-mode, auto-mode-alist

How do I make Emacs automatically turn on `diff-mode` for any file with diff-looking content, eg.

```
--- a.txt
+++ b.txt
@@ -1234,56 +1234,56 @@
```

Answer (score 3):

`C-h v magic-mode-alist` says this:

> **`magic-mode-alist`** is a variable defined in `files.el`.
>   Its value is `nil`
>
> This variable can be risky when used as a file-local variable.
>
> Documentation:
>
> Alist of buffer beginnings vs. corresponding major mode functions.
>   Each element looks like `(REGEXP . FUNCTION)` or `(MATCH-FUNCTION . FUNCTION)`.
>   After visiting a file, if `REGEXP` matches the text at the beginning of the
>   buffer, or calling `MATCH-FUNCTION` returns non-`nil`, `normal-mode` will
>   call `FUNCTION` rather than allowing `auto-mode-alist` to decide the buffer's
>   major mode.
>
> If `FUNCTION` is `nil`, then it is not called.  (That is a way of saying
>   "allow `auto-mode-alist` to decide for these files.")

So either use a `REGEXP` that distinguishes the beginning of the buffer text or use `MATCH-FUNCTION` that does so.

See also `C-h v magic-fallback-mode-alist`:

> **`magic-fallback-mode-alist`** is a variable defined in `files.el`.
>   Its value is shown below.
>
> This variable can be risky when used as a file-local variable.
>
> Documentation:
>
> Like `magic-mode-alist` but has lower priority than `auto-mode-alist`.
>   Each element looks like `(REGEXP . FUNCTION)` or `(MATCH-FUNCTION . FUNCTION)`.
>   After visiting a file, if `REGEXP` matches the text at the beginning of the
>   buffer, or calling `MATCH-FUNCTION` returns non-`nil`, `normal-mode` will
>   call `FUNCTION`, **provided that `magic-mode-alist` and `auto-mode-alist`
>   have not specified a mode for this file**.
>
> If `FUNCTION` is `nil`, then it is not called.
>
> Value:
>
> ```
>   ((image-type-auto-detected-p . image-mode)
>      ("\\(PK00\\)?[P]K" . archive-mode)
>      ("\\(?:<\\?xml[    
>        \n]+[^>]*>\\)?[
>
>        \n]*<\\(?:!--\\(?:[^-]\\|-[^-]\\)*-->[
>
>        \n]*<\\)*\\(?:!DOCTYPE[    
>        \n]+[^>]*>[  
>        \n]*<[
>
>        \n]*\\(?:!--\\(?:[^-]\\|-[^-]\\)*-->[
>
>        \n]*<\\)*\\)?[Hh][Tt][Mm][Ll]" . mhtml-mode)
>      ("<!DOCTYPE[
>
>        \n]+[Hh][Tt][Mm][Ll]" . mhtml-mode)
>      ("<\\?xml " . xml-mode)
>      ("[
>
>        \n]*<\\(?:!--\\(?:[^-]\\|-[^-]\\)*-->[     
>        \n]*<\\)*!DOCTYPE " . sgml-mode)
>      ("%!PS" . ps-mode)
>      ("# xmcd " . conf-unix-mode))
> ```

See also the Emacs manual, node [Choosing Modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html).